# array of strings with dot in string(nested) to array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array :

```
"country": ["name", "units.size", "units.weight", "formats.date", "formats.number"]
```

i want in result to get the the following array :

```
"country": ["name", "units", "formats"]
```

I want to get just the object name without the nested attributes.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let country = ["name", "units.size", "units.weight", "formats.date", "formats.number"];

country = [...new Set(country.map(a => a.match(/\w+/)[0]))];

console.log(country);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach()` to iterate over the array and push each category to a new array.

In your `forEach()` you can use `indexOf()` to check if the category already exists.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const countries = { "country": ["name", "units.size", "units.weight", "formats.date", "formats.number"] };

countries.country = [...new Set(countries.country.map((item) => item.includes('.') ? item.split('.')[0] : item))]
console.log(countries);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this simply by mapping through a the array and splitting the entries on the first `.`. After that use the [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to remove duplicates:

```js
let country = ["name", "units.size", "units.weight", "formats.date", "formats.number"];

let result = [...new Set(country.map(x => x.split('.')[0]))]

console.log(result)
```